# JavaScript prototype delegation in function

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototypal-inheritance, delegation

I am trying to learn Javascript but I am finding this prototype concept very confusing someone helps me with this code snippet

```
var func = function (){};
func.prototype = {m:9};

func.prototype.m; // That logs 9

func.m; // That logs undefined
```

Why is the delegation not working in this case?

Comment: How does this code "log" anything?

Comment: It was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Comment: The prototype only becomes relevant when you *instantiate* a new object using `new func`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a constructor function that has `m` in its prototype.

```
var func = function (){};
func.prototype = {m:9};

console.log( func.prototype.m ); // That logs 9
```

The prototype is assigned **not to the function itself** but to instances created by this function:

```
var f = new func();

console.log( f.m ); // That also logs 9
```

This is where your `m` is.

For this to also log 9

```
func.m
```

you'd have to have `m` in `Function.prototype` because the prototype of `func` is `Function`

```
Function.prototype.m = 9;

console.log( func.m ); // Logs 9
```

Answer (score 4):

By doing `func.prototype = {m:9};`, you are setting the *'prototype'* property of your `func` variable to `{m:9}`.

When you call, `func.m`, you try to access the *'m'*  property of your `func` variable, which you never set before.

Instead, you previously set the *'m'* property of the object `func.prototype`.

If you want to set the property *'m'* from your variable `func`, simply do `func.m = 9;`